# Same Modal are not popping out in two separate file

Tags: php, bootstrap-4

I having trouble to open one modal in two separate php file

This is my modal code(workerSurveyModal.php)

```
<!-- Modal of Renew&Update Survey Decision for Worker -->
<div class="modal fade" id="workerSurveyDecisionModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="workerSurveyDecisionModalDecisionModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="workerSurveyDecisionModalLabel">Worker Survey Decision:</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <form method="POST" id="formWorkerSurveyResult" action="action/fn_setData.php?mod=renewSurveyResult">
                <div class="modal-body">
                <input type="hidden" id="responseId" name="responseId" >
                <input type="text" id="workerId" name="workerId" >
                <input type="text" id="contractEndDate" name="contractEndDate" >
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="response">Worker Survey Decision:</label>
                        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="response" id="responseYes" value="YES" required>
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="responseYes">YES</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="response" id="responseNo" value="NO" required>
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="responseNo">NO</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="form-group" id="reasonDropdownlist" style="display: none;">
                        <label for="reason">Reason for Not Renewing:</label>
                        <select class="form-control" name="reason" id="reason" required>
                            <option selected></option>
                            <option>Personal issue</option>
                            <option>Family issue</option>
                            <option>Other reason</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Textbox for "Other reason" -->
                    <div class="form-group" id="otherReasonTextbox" style="display:none;">
                        <label for="otherReason">Please specify Other Reason:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="otherReason" id="otherReason" placeholder="Please specify the reason...">
                    </div>

                    <br>

                    <!-- Dropdownlist for "destination" -->
                    <div class="form-group" id="destinationDropdownlist" style="display: none;">
                        <label for="destination">Selected Destination:</label>
                        <select class="form-control" name="destination" id="destination" required>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="changeDecision">Allow Worker to Change Decision:</label>
                        <select class="form-control" name="changeDecision" id="changeDecision" required>
                            <option selected></option>
                            <option>YES</option>
                            <option>NO</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Textbox for Remarks -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="remarks">Remarks:</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="remarks" name="remarks" rows="3"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    

                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSubmit">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- End of Modal of Renew&Update Survey Decision -->
```

Now I want to call the Modal in two separate php file

tabSurveyPending.php

```
<?php
    session_start();

    require ("workerSurveyModal.php");

?>
```

tabCompleted.php

```
<?php
    session_start();

    require ("workerSurveyModal.php");

?>
```

I only can call the modal in one php file which is tabSurveyPending and in tabSurveyCompleted, the modal is not popping out. I could not identify the solution

Can anyone help me and I will appreciate your help. Thank you

Comment: The issue you're facing might be because you're including the same modal with the same ID in two different files.

Comment: Yes but I am using the same modal, so how I can change the id for two separate file